# Stripe integration error Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, xcode-6.2

To be specific i get this error when i build my project after adding the stripe framework.The project is for the iOS platform.

I have all the standard architectures added to my build settings namely 
armv7,armv7s. This is the error logged,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_STPAPIClient", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PlaceOrderViewController.o
```

After this error came i added arm64 also. I got error from this class alone as i'm calling a method from STPAPIClient.h in the Stripe framework.I have tried everywhere on the internet including stack and found nothing that could solve the issue.Hope someone can provide insights as to why this is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the solution for me was to copy the entire stripe project, **stripe.xcodeproj** into my project. This would only bring that file so to bring all the classes in stripe project I copied the stripe workspace,**stripe.xcworkspace** into my project folder.

This solved all architecture related issues.